# Sorting labels per row/column

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3),
columns = ['A','B','C'], 
index   = ['r0', 'r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4')

          A         B         C
r0 -0.830305 -0.395235  0.589917
r1 -1.378534 -0.484204 -1.068907
r2 -0.407720  1.922942 -1.120012
r3  1.075495  0.968913  1.509079
r4 -2.858858  1.018327 -0.660672
```

I would like to get a new data frame where, for each row, I have the list of column names sorted by value.

For the example above, the result of sorting in `descending order` by column would be:

```
    0  1  2
r0  C  B  A
r1  A  B  C
r2  B  A  C
r3  C  A  B
r4  B  C  A
```

Is there a "Pandas/numpy" way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the [`order`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.order.html) Series method on each row (and take the index):

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
           A         B         C
r0  0.213505 -0.661328  1.489605
r1 -1.096459 -0.373994 -1.948745
r2  0.380518 -1.424787 -0.639996
r3 -0.327361  1.029477  0.153808
r4 -0.593371  0.112844  0.096872

In [12]: df.apply(lambda row: row.order(ascending=False).index, axis=1)
Out[12]:
    A  B  C
r0  C  A  B
r1  B  A  C
r2  A  C  B
r3  B  C  A
r4  B  C  A
```

To break it down:

```
In [21]: row = df.ix[0]

In [22]: row
Out[22]:
A    0.213505
B   -0.661328
C    1.489605
Name: r0

In [23]: row.order(ascending=False)
Out[23]:
C    1.489605
A    0.213505
B   -0.661328
Name: r0

In [24]: row.order(ascending=False).index
Out[24]: Index([C, A, B], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I think I like this better than mine.

Comment: `In[12]` returns the following: `/opt/Python-2.7.3-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.10.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py:3576: FutureWarning: rename with inplace=True  will return None from pandas 0.11 onward                               " from pandas 0.11 onward", FutureWarning)` What does that mean? Will the code that you wrote be compatible with `0.11` onward?

Comment: @user815423426 it works (without the warning) on the 0.11 dev. As to why you see it: good question (since we aren't calling rename)... There is going to be [an API change](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html) where many functions when called with inplace=True will return None (rather than the output). Since we aren't using inplace=True, this isn't a problem here.